# responsive grid in HTML and CSS

Tags: responsive

I need to create a responsive grid in HTML and CSS like in this sketch. The 4 smallest boxes should contain a font-awesome icon.

I already tried it with bootstrap, but it's necessary, that the space between icon and img stays the same and is not so big.

Thank you for your suggestions.

[Layout Wireframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLpe6.png)

Comment: *I already tried it with bootstrap* You should include that code in your question. Without it, *img stays the same and is not so big* doesn't make sense because we can't see what's going wrong with your attempt.

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make them *position:fixed* or *position:absolute* (depending on what else is on your page; probably you'll go with *fixed*), then use calc() to get the positions, see this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/k79ouu0u/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> Boxes </title>
    <style>

        .center-box {
            position:fixed;
            top :calc(50% - 100px); height:200px;
            left:calc(50% - 100px); width :200px;
        }

        .left-panel {
            position:fixed;
            top:calc(50% - 40px);height:80px;
            left:10px;width:calc(50% - 10px - 100px - 10px);
        }

        .right-panel {                                                              
            position:fixed;
            top:calc(50% - 40px);height:80px;
            left:calc(50% + 100px + 10px);width:calc(50% - 10px - 100px - 10px);
        }

        .top-panel {
            position:fixed;
            left:calc(50% - 30px);right:10px;
            height:80px; top:calc(50% - 100px - 80px - 10px);
        }

        .bottom-panel {
            position:fixed;
            left:calc(50% - 30px);right:10px;
            height:80px; top:calc(50% + 100px + 0px + 10px);
        }


        .center-box    {background:red;border:1px solid black}  
        .left-panel    {background:green;border:1px solid black}    
        .top-panel     {background:green;border:1px solid black}    
        .bottom-panel  {background:green;border:1px solid black}    
        .right-panel   {background:green;border:1px solid black}    

    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="center-box"></div>
    <div class="left-panel"></div>
    <div class="right-panel"></div>
    <div class="top-panel"></div>
    <div class="bottom-panel"></div>


</body>
</html>
```

When you're done, try a responsive tester tool (like http://reframe.deneskellner.com - yes, that's my home-made one) to see if they move around nicely.